# Find my Mac if thief erased it

Tags: ipad, mac

My Mac was stolen.

I bought an iPad to use find my Mac. The computer was going online and I was getting notifications.  Unfortunately I was not at my iPad at the time.

After the Sheriffs office got my computer back it was completely wiped out. I had to put in my passcode to reinstall the OS.

My question is after the computer played a sound I suspect it was then erased to avoid detection. After the Mac was erased, could the Mac ping online while the thieves attempted to reinstall the OS without my passcode?

Comment: There's a honey trap if they try to boot it - they can get into the Guest account. That is enough to spring the Find My Mac connection if there's wifi nearby that they can access. Figuring out *exactly* what they did is probably not possible though.

Comment: Stolen Dec19, 2018 receiving spam on my Farm email account on Dec 27, 2018.  Got iPad on Jan 16, 2019. Used personal email account to setup the iPad.  Neighbors grandson had stolen computer and took to his friends house. Used Find MY Mac accidently hit play a sound.  Received an email that on February 21, at 10:30 am the computer played a sound.  On Feb25, 2018 the girl called and opened a case number to apple unaware that Apple was sending me the emails to reach her about the stolen computer. Claims the computer was locked up the whole time it was there. How do I prove that a lie in court?